# Use 'paths' to access different levels of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to define a little wrapper function that takes some sort of 'path' to access different levels of nested dictionaries:

```
D = {'key1': valueA,
     'key2': {'key21': valueB,
             {'key22': valueC}
```

In this simple example, I'd like to write a function that as argument takes, for example, a tuple like

```
dict_path = ('key2', 'key22')

>>>nested_getter(dict_path)
valueC
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in your "question". Just an objective and an implied "GO!".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def nested_getter(d, keys):
    return reduce(dict.get, keys, d)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
D = {'key1': valueA,
     'key2': {'key21': valueB,
              'key22': valueC}}


def nested_getter(root, path):
    for elem in path:
        root = root[elem]
    return root
```

With this you can do:

```
>>> nested_getter(D, ('key2', 'key22'))
3
```

Comment: I'd do it with `*args` to avoid the extra parentheses.